# npm start error. New react native app... Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, create-react-native-app

I am having an issue running "npm start" after using create-react-native-app for the first time. I installed create-react-native-app global and ran it. Then I cd into my new app and tried to "npm start". I get the error below. I also added the full error log. I think my PATH is the issue but, I'm not sure. I'm using windows 8.1. Thank you so much for any advice!

```
PS C:\Desktop\devout> npm start

> my-new-project@ start C:\Desktop\devout
> expo start

[11:43:43] Starting project at C:\Desktop\devout
[11:43:53] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[11:43:53] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
 events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-new-project@ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-new-project@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\first baptist\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11- 
13T16_44_06_257Z-debug.log
```

Full Log...

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm- 
cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle my-new-project@~prestart: my-new-project@
6 info lifecycle my-new-project@~start: my-new-project@
7 verbose lifecycle my-new-project@~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-new-project@~start: PATH: C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp- 
bin;C:\Desktop\devout\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program files\nodejs;C:\Program 
Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\program 
files\git;C:\Users\first baptist\Miniconda3;C:\Users\first 
baptist\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\first 
baptist\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\first 
baptist\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\first 
baptist\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\first 
baptist\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program 
Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\public\software\Microsoft VS 
Code\bin;C:\Users\first baptist\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin 
9 verbose lifecycle my-new-project@~start: CWD: C:\Desktop\devout
10 silly lifecycle my-new-project@~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-new-project@~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-new-project@~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: my-new-project@ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14) 
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-new-project@
15 verbose cwd C:\Desktop\devout
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v8.12.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-new-project@ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-new-project@ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I suspect that it can't open your browser. Can you run it with pressing `shif-d` ?

Comment: I have tried pressing it but, it doesn’t change the outcome. I’m entering it when that line appears.

Answer (score 1):

try yarn...
or install watchman.

But i recommend update your node version to 10.0.0
before up

Comment: My version is updated to node: 11.1.0 and npm: 6.4.1

Comment: try npm start -- --reset-cache

Answer (score 1):

See the current version of node js on your system and check all the dependencies before starting the server. I believe the issue is with updates of either. Try installing all the updates.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I installed the latest versions. Same outcome though.

Comment: Okay. Is `events.js` one of your files or is it in the package? And secondly,
`npm ERR! Failed at the my-new-project@ start script.` states that the error is in the project and not in npm. Check your files again. Let me know if this works.

Comment: There is no event.js in the project. This is just the automatic files created by create-react-native-app I have not modified them

Comment: I also created a new project to see if it was in the install. Same result.